# php functions file_exits, copy, shell_exec not working on one machine but same code working on different machine

Tags: php, apache, slim, shell-exec, file-exists

I am a Centos 7 machine on which I have configured PHP with Apache and Slim Framework.

The simple code to check if the file exists and copy the code into a directory is working fine on one of the machine but not working on another machine. Its really weird.

Actually I am accessing the API through Apache to trigger this function.

Functions like shell_exec alaways return 0
copy function is also not workingg
file_exists also not working.

Any help or clue why this is wrong or debug this issue.

Comment: Could be different settings of [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) or [safe_mode_exec_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir) or event [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) maybe?

Comment: I second Alon's point on php's security setting the the .ini file. Also make sure the error_reporting is on to see any errors encountered.

Comment: I tried to debug it further and found that it is working for a normal php script but when the same script get called from the apache (web) it is not working. Checked open_basedir/ disable_function  nothing is configured so still wondering why it is not working from apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help.

Problem was file permission issue.
The reason was all of the above function  I was performing was on the file. Since the files has different permission for different user.

So If I hit the URL from browser it was through "Apache" user which does not have execute permission on the folder to access the file and read permission on the file.

In short

> sudo chmod +rx file
>
> sudo chmod +x "All the directory structure"